# R: How to insert a row in Dataframe starting at a certain column?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, extract

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1, z = 4:6, a = 6:4, b = 7:9)
```

I now need to extract the values from the second row, third to fifth column with this command:

```
newrow <- df[2,3:5]
```

I now want to insert a new row after the second row. The problem is that I need the new row to start at column 2. If I use the following code, the row will be added at the same column positions as I extracted it from:

```
df%>% add_row(newrow, .before = 3)
```

Hope anybody can help with this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check `bind_rows()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `newrow` dataframe has the colnames from coluns 3:5 (z,a,b). Therefore `add_row()`matches the newrow to these columns.

You need to rename the columns of newrow with the first three column names.

```
df%>% add_row(setNames(newrow, names(df)[1:ncol(newrow)]),
              .before = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're desired outcome is but does this achieve what you want?

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tibble(x = 1:3, y = 3:1, z = 4:6, a = 6:4, b = 7:9)

whatrow <- 2
whatcolumns <- 3:5
beforerow <- 3

newdf <- 
   slice(df, whatrow) %>% 
   select(all_of(whatcolumns)) %>% 
   setNames(., names(df)[whatcolumns - 1]) %>%  
   add_row(df, ., .before = beforerow)
newdf
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>       x     y     z     a     b
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     3     4     6     7
#> 2     2     2     5     5     8
#> 3    NA     5     5     8    NA
#> 4     3     1     6     4     9
```